# Small signal analysis of MOSFET. Calculating Gain

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis, gain

I can do DC analysis and draw the small signal equivalent circuit just fine. I generally have trouble calculating gain. I'm having trouble understanding the answer to this question.

This is the question. Question 4.36: [image: The Question]

This is my working. I hope it is clear:

[image]
According to the solution manual this is the wrong answer. The correct answer is $$A_v = \frac{V_o}{V_o + 1}$$:
[image]

I don't understand. \$V_i\$ is in parallel with \$V_{sg}\$ therefore \$V_i\$ must equal \$V_{sg}\$ right? Where did I make a mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Vi is not Vgs, look carefully at the circuit, it's a common drain !
Vi = Vo - Vgs

Also: your small signal equivalent circuit is for a common source while the assignment 4.36 is for a **common drain**! Note that it is a PMOS with the arrow (indicating the source) at the resistor Rs side.

Comment: Actually Vgs is DC and it is AC coupled

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Your comment is confusing. Vgs is not DC only. Vgs consists of a DC component (the biasing, this makes a quiescent Id flow) **plus** an AC component determined by both Vi (via an AC coupling: Cc1) **and** Vo (also via an AC coupling: Cc2).

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 I think it is correct. Care to enlighten us why you think it is incorrect? "It doesn't look right" is not much to go by.

Comment: \$G_i=R_G/R_L (approx)~~~ g_mR_L>>1\$

Comment: consider  \$G_v=\dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{R_L+r_o}{g_m~R_L~r_o}}\$  what does \$V_o\$ have to do with small sig gain. and it is a common source not common drain.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Oh, I think I see the confusion here, the **assignment** 4.36 is a **common drain** but OP's small signal equivalent is of a **common source** and therefore **wrong** (for this assignment). I didn't even look at it since it's not rotated properly, I was only paying attention to the parts reprinted from the book.

Comment: I meant to say that too. So I fixed the photo for all.